# What programming language is used in integrating a panoramic view in an HTML site? How can I highlight some parts in the panoramic view?

Tags: html, flash, web

(http://themes.siiimple.com/themeselector/?theme=360)

(http://www.airpano.ru/files/Seattle-USA/2-2)

(http://360gigapixels.com/london-320-gigapixel-panorama/)

(http://www.paris-26-gigapixels.com/index-en.html)

The above links are some of the examples.

Answer (score 1):

You can use flash action Script , or webgl JavaScript... I promote the second option really as its not flash dependant..
Below is an example with source code:

http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_panorama_equirectangular

Try three.js library it has great documentation and API...
[image: illustration]

Added image for a visual idea

Comment: but how to highlight any particular object in this panoramic view @careen

Comment: Really that was plenty of info for a solution, be realistic you could add objects in the room with transparent to 0, and than use ray cast to pick on object ina  3d scene add your own function...to me it seems your after a completed solution working and ready for you to use...please read the three.js examples ray picking that will be enough to complete the task..

Comment: Not really but i want to know the information how exactly it works, because no person can simple ask for all the work and uploading it as his own work. seriously no honest man will use it has its own work with out sweating.

Comment: All them examples give you source code, that's why the authors have put the their , they are more than willing for you to do with what you like... and share knowledge on how to use the library.. Im not sure what else you need to know